# How do I pass through options when defining a new environment?

Tags: environments, optional-arguments

I'm trying to define a new environment that's a customized version of the `itemize` environment, where any options that I pass to the new environment get passed through to the underlying `itemize`. **For example**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newenvironment{itemOpt}[1][]%
{%
    \begin{itemize}[#1]
    % some customization here
}%
{%
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemOpt}
  \item abc
\end{itemOpt}

\begin{itemOpt}[leftmargin=1in]
  \item abc
\end{itemOpt}
\end{document}
```

However, this throws a `missing \item` error. What am I doing wrong?

**Note: I'm just using `itemize` as an example here.**

Comment: Consider `enumitem` package before defining new `itemize` environments

Comment: And avoid the `minimal` class.

Comment: @egreg Noted. I updated the question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll look into the `enumitem` package more. I initially defined a new environment because I didn't want to change any settings globally, or each time I called the `itemize` environment. I was just using `itemize` as an example here.

Comment: @MichaelA: You can clone the `itemize` list with `\newlist` and set your special values with `\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=1in}` etc. Anyway, the `[#1]` confuses `\itemize` ;-)

Comment: The `itemize` environment doesn't take an optional argument but you are assuming it does. With `enumitem` you can say `\newlist{}{}{}` and then `\setlist[]{}` to define custom lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumitem` has it all when it comes to customizing the list`. Instead of writing a new environment, you can change the properties on the fly. Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item abc
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1in]
  \item abc
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The options can be globally fixed using `\setlist`, one can define a new list by cloning basic lists, attributes can be changed mid way etc. For details, see the manual.

here is a sample of new list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitem]{label=$\bullet$,itemsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitem}
  \item abc
\end{myitem}

\begin{myitem}[leftmargin=1in]
  \item abc
\end{myitem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MichaelA OK time to define a new list. 2 mins.